# Is it possible to minimize window when it has tray?

Tags: electron

Is it possible to use `.minimize()` on window (Windows OS) when it has tray? Now I'd like to hide it into windows dock (Or how is it called?), but when I have tray in an app and trying to call `.minimize()` on browser window, nothing happens. Sure, I can use `.hide()` instead, but I'd like to keep it in dock instead of just fully hiding it.
I'm using Electron 10.1.1.

For example:

```js
  // First we have to create the window
  const { BrowserWindow, Tray } = require('electron')

  const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
  win.loadURL('https://github.com');

  // Then we have to create tray
  const tray = new Tray('/path/to/my/icon')
  const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    { label: 'Item1', type: 'radio' },
    { label: 'Item2', type: 'radio' },
    { label: 'Item3', type: 'radio', checked: true },
    { label: 'Item4', type: 'radio' }
  ])
  tray.setToolTip('This is my application.')
  tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu)

  // Here we expect application will be hidden into windows dock, but nothing happens.
  win.minimize()
```

Will appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: You write `const = new Tray(..)`. This gives an error, of course: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='`. Without it, it runs fine and the window minimizes right after startup.

Comment: @snwflk it would be good to have just syntax error. :) It's just my mistake when I've made an example. Real source code has no syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs fine if the BrowserWindow is created when the app is ready.

```js
const {app,BrowserWindow,Tray,Menu} = require("electron");
const path = require("path");

let win, tray;

app.on("ready", function() {

  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
  win.loadURL("https://github.com");

  const trayIcon = path.join(__dirname, "icon.png");
  tray = new Tray(trayIcon);

  const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    { label: "Item1", type: "radio" },
    { label: "Item2", type: "radio" },
    { label: "Item3", type: "radio", checked: true },
    { label: "Item4", type: "radio" }
  ]);
  tray.setToolTip("This is my application.");
  tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu);

  win.minimize();
});
```

When trying to create the BrowserWindow without waiting for the [`ready`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-ready) event, you should get the following error:

> Error: Cannot create BrowserWindow before app is ready